# Redirecting all traffic to www https

Tags: apache, tomcat, redirect, https

My application is running on Apache hosted on Ubuntu and I want the following re - directions to work:

```
1> http://example.com       -> https://www.example.com
2> http://www.example.com   -> https://www.example.com
3> https://example.com      -> https://www.example.com
```

I am using the following lines in my default apache config file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)         https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R]
```

This way , the first two redirections work fine but the third one does not. Is the third one possible? if yes how?

Thanks.

Comment: think it should be `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]`

Comment: I tried that but it did not solve my problem. Moreover it redirected
mysite.com to "https : //www.mysite.com//" (two trailing /)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 4):

I have a site that I want all traffic coming into a virtual host to go to port 443. I set up the virtual host definition for port 80 redirection as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)         https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R]
```

This will redirect any traffic coming into port 80 to 443.

Make sure that you have your ServerName and ServerAlias set up correctly. In this example you would have something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.* example.* example.com

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
        RewriteRule .* - [F]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACK
        RewriteRule .* - [F]

        #redirect all port 80 traffic to 443
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
        RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R]
    </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

After this you would set up a 443 virtualhost definition as well (less the port rewrite section).

Comment: Well, this results in *"The page isn’t redirecting properly"* with nothing written to `error_log`.

Comment: Here is another configuration option example:https://coderwall.com/p/yvg2zw/forward-all-apache-http-traffic-to-https

Comment: For whatever reason, you rules for virtual host on port 80 breaks HSTS headers under the 443 virtual host.

Comment: Could be because the R flag by default is a 302(temporary) redirect? Not sure. I should mention I hate Apache configs, and this worked for my situation 4 years ago on a project. Here's a similar post on SF with explicit R=301 declaration: http://serverfault.com/questions/570288/is-it-bad-to-redirect-http-to-https

Comment: Yeah, Apache pretty much sucks. I've given up on [configuring a server properly on my own](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321380/56041). We reached out to the [Free Software Foundation for help](https://www.fsf.org/resources/service/) to get this server configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been a while, but I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)         https://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R]
```

The key part being the `S` in `%{HTTPS_HOST}`

You should be able to place that right after what you already have.